# Reach element in an object inside an array which is an element in an object inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I've tried to reach an element in object inside an array which is an element in an object inside an array. Look at the code under. The thirdElementInObject has variable length. My plan is to make list element with every object in the mainArray. I haven't made it with the elements in the thirdElementInObject array. Does anyone know how I can do this?

```
mainArray = [
   {firstElementInObject: xyz,
   secondElementInObject: abc,
   thirdElementInObject: [
     {name: zzz,
     age: aaa,
     },
     {name: cde,
     age: 123,
     },
     ],
},
   {firstElementInObject: xyz,
   secondElementInObject: abc,
   thirdElementInObject: [
     {name: xxx,
     age: yyy,
     },
     {name: abc,
     age: def,
     },
     {name: abc,
     age: def,
     }
     ],
}
]

const parentElementDash = document.querySelector('.mainArrayUl');

const updateHTML = function () {  
    if (mainArray.length > 0) {
        let result = mainArray.map(element => {
            return `
                <li>
                    <p>${element.firstElementInObject}</p>
                    <p>${element.secondElementInObject}</p>

                    /* Here I want to write the name in the 
                   thirdElementInObject. */

                </li>`  
        });
        parentElementDash.innerHTML = result.join('');
    }
}


updateHTML();
```

Comment: _"Here I want to write the name in the thirdElementInObject"_ do you want to get all the names or only the first one?

Comment: Is `element.thirdElementInObjet[index].name` the syntax you are looking for ? With `index` with the index of the object in the array you want to access.

Comment: @ruleboy21

I want to get all the names.

Comment: @Krafpy

I have tried that, but I need all the names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can get all the names as an array using `.map()`.
- You can then use `.join()` to convert the array to string and insert
  it in the HTML.

Try this

```js
var mainArray = [
    {
        firstElementInObject: 'xyz',
        secondElementInObject: 'abc',
        thirdElementInObject: [
            {name: 'zzz', age: 'aaa',},
            {name: 'cde', age: 123,},
        ],
    },
    {
        firstElementInObject: 'xyz',
        secondElementInObject: 'abc',
        thirdElementInObject: [
            {name: 'xxx', age: 'yyy',},
            {name: 'abc', age: 'def',},
            {name: 'abc', age: 'def',}
        ],
    }
]

const parentElementDash = document.querySelector('.mainArrayUl');

const updateHTML = function () {  
    if (mainArray.length > 0) {
        let result = mainArray.map(element => {
            return `
                <li>
                    <p>${element.firstElementInObject}</p>
                    <p>${element.secondElementInObject}</p>
                    <p>${element.thirdElementInObject.map(({name}) => name).join(', ')}</p>
                </li>`  
        });
        parentElementDash.innerHTML = result.join('');
    }
}

updateHTML();
```

```html
<ul class="mainArrayUl"></ul>
```